# How is the omitted variable bias formula derived?

Tags: regression, omitted-variable-bias

I see it is often quoted that the omitted variable bias formula is

$$
\text{Bias}\left(\widehat{\beta_1}\right) = \beta_2 \cdot \text{Corr}\left(X_2,X_1\right)
$$

where $\widehat{\beta_1}$ is the estimated coefficient in the biased model, $\beta_2$ is the true coefficient of the omitted variable $X_2$ in the full model.

I am wondering how this is derived generally. Thanks.

Comment: A little units analysis suggests this formula is not correct, but it will be if we assume these are *standardized* coefficients.  After all, the units of measurement of $\hat\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ usually differ (the first is in units of the response per unit of $X_1$ while the second is units of response per unit of $X_2$) but a correlation is *unitless.*  Thus, your equation can possibly hold *only* in circumstances where $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same units, which would not be a general formula.

Comment: @whuber Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example of how one analyzes such a situation.  Suppose that the model

$$E[Y\mid X_1,X_2] = \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2$$

holds where $X_1,$ $X_2,$ and $Y$ are random $n$-vectors.  If you omit the second variable and use the wrong model (omitting the $X_2$ variable)

$$E[Y\mid X] = \gamma_1 X_1,$$

we may ask what error you might expect in using an estimate of $\gamma_1$ to estimate $\beta_1.$  When you use ordinary least squares regression to estimate $\gamma_1,$ the formula is

$$\hat\gamma_1 = \frac{Y\cdot X_1}{X_1\cdot X_1}.$$

Using the correct model formulation you may compute

$$E[\hat\gamma_1\mid X_1, X_2] = E\left[\frac{Y\cdot X_1}{X_1\cdot X_1}\mid X_1,X_2\right] = E\left[\frac{(\beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2)\cdot X_1}{X_1\cdot X_1}\mid X_1,X_2\right].$$

Basic properties of expectation (linearity) and conditional expectation (taking out what is known) allow you to simplify the right hand side to

$$E[\hat\gamma_1\mid X_1, X_2] = \beta_1 + \beta_2 \frac{X_2\cdot X_1}{X_1\cdot X_1}.$$

By definition, the (conditional) *bias* in an estimate is the difference between its expectation and estimand,

> $$\text{bias} = E[\hat\gamma_1\mid X_1,X_2] - \beta_1 = \beta_2 \frac{X_2\cdot X_1}{X_1\cdot X_1}.$$

That is a general formula, applicable for fixed $X_i$ or for random $X_i$ where $X_1\cdot X_1$ is almost surely nonzero.  Already the result is helpful, because it implies that when $X_1$ is *orthogonal* to $X_2$ (which is just a way of saying the numerator is zero), the bias is *zero;* and otherwise it shows that the bias is nonzero and it gives you information about its sign and magnitude.

If, additionally, you arrange for the $X_i$ to be standardized (which means their components sum to zero and the squares of their components sum to unity), the fraction on the right could be called the "correlation" of $X_1$ and $X_2,$ *understanding this term to be a shorthand for*

$$\operatorname{correlation}(X_1,X_2) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_{1i}X_{2i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_{1i}X_{1i}} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_{1i}X_{2i}}{1} = \sum_{i=1}^n X_{1i}X_{2i},$$

which is the Pearson correlation of standardized vectors.  But please note that this is *not* the correlation in the sense that $X_1$ and $X_2$ might be random vectors: the bias was computed *conditionally* and still depends on $X_1$ and $X_2.$  If, for instance, each $X_i$ were an *iid* sequence of random values drawn from a bivariate distribution, that underlying distribution can have a correlation but it's unlikely to equal the value computed in the bias formula.

Comment: Thank you so very much for this.